# GWT SuperDevMode divide options

Tags: gwt

How can you divide the project into two parts?
1) When I run in SuperDevMode mode. Your resources and * .gwt.xml
2) When I compile in maven. Special resource and * .gwt.xml.

For example my properties

```
svn.revision=${buildNumber}
#dbo.url=${dbo.url}
dbo.url=https://localhost:9990/server/
#show.error.dialog=${errorDialog}
show.error.dialog=true
```

Depending on the conditions. SuperDev or Maven. I must uncomment the necessary lines and comment out the unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven-antrun-plugin to copy stuff into the build when you create the war file to be deployed.
[Maven Antrun Plugin documentantion and examples.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html)

Your question is very abstract. Can you make a more concrete example of which kind of resources you need to copy and why. This will allow us to give you better suggestions and solutions.

Comment: I add some info

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.

It is not recommended to add configuration in your code, you may transform all those in environment variables so when you run in production the server will have the production db url set and when your run locally from your IDE you can set the var pointing to the test database.

Heroku has a pretty good example of this concept:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Can I ask also one question? How to be with module.gwt.xml? For exmaple in SuperDevMode I want use  <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>. In maven  <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="FALSE"/>

Comment: You can check the http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#isProdMode-- and turn on/off logging in the onModuleLoad